# How to Write the javascript Function in Asp.net MVC aspx View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Hi is there anyone who can help me with the following. I am having asp.net mvc aspx page ,i want to write javascript function but i am stuck as how i call that function ....

My function of javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                                        function toTimeString(d) {

                                            d = parse(d);
                                            var h = d.getHours();
                                            var s = "AM";
                                            if (h > 12) {
                                                h = h - 12;
                                                s = "PM";
                                            }
                                            var m = d.getMinutes();
                                            if (m < 10) {
                                                m = "0" + m;
                                            } else {
                                                m = m + "";
                                                if (m.length == 1) {
                                                    m = m + "0";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            return h + ":" + m + " " + s;
                                        }

                                        function  parse(v) {
                                            if (!v)
                                                return null;
                                            if (!(v.constructor == String))
                                                return v;
                                            if (/^\/date\([\-0-9]+\)\//gi.test(v)) {
                                                v = new Date(parseInt(v.substr(6), 10));
                                            } else {
                                                if (/^\/dateiso/gi.test(v)) {
                                                    v = v.substr(9);
                                                    v = v.substr(0, v.length - 1);
                                                    var tokens = v.split('T');
                                                    var date = tokens[0];
                                                    var time = tokens[1];
                                                    date = date.split('-');
                                                    time = time.split(':');
                                                    var d = new Date(date[0], parseInt(date[1]) - 1, date[2], time[0], time[1], parseFloat(time[2]));
                                                    d = new Date(d.getTime() + AtomDate.zoneOffset);
                                                    return d;
                                                } else {
                                                    v = Date.parse(v);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            return v;
                                        }

</script>
```

and i am tried to call in the html like

```
<span style="font-size: 23px"><%= c.StartDate != null ?  toTimeString(c.StartDate.Value): ""%></span>
```

but i am not being able to call toTimeString ,Please Help me Out

Comment: to call the function use like `toTimeString()` where you need.

Comment: Its not working ,Gives error ,The Name toTimeString does not exist in current context

Answer (score 0):

to init this function use:

```
<span style="font-size: 23px">
<script type="text\javascript">
<%= c.StartDate != null ?  toTimeString(c.StartDate.Value): ""%>
</script>
</span>
```

you need to understand that when the page is rendered the javascript is just placed on the page that being sent to client, look at this as a cake recipe that is ready to pass over to someone else to use it.
the real sheaf (still using the analogy) is the browser that gets the recipe and follow the instruction  and that's why you need to wrap you'r javascript with `<script type="text\javascript">`

Comment: Where did you placed this function?

Comment: javascript function is placed in between the script tag in html head and i call the function the way u suggest above like   <%= c.StartDate != null ?  toTimeString(c.StartDate.Value): ""%>

Comment: the span is located in an iframe? if so that may cause this, if not please attach you'r html page fully or add a fiddle, for more help